# Copy & Paste visible and filtered ells into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have some code that hides columns then copies and pastes into a new workbook to be used by the end user away from the main workbook as a feedback tool. the code works absolutely fine if the source worksheet doesn't have a filter applied but once the end user has applied a filter the code breaks and an error message and no data is copied.

This is the code that I am using;

```
Sub Create_Export_Summary_View()
'
'Description: This Macro will had all columns showing in the Summary View code and
'produce a new, locked down, copy for the HRA/HRBP to share with their customers
'
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Master")

ws.Unprotect "Reward18"

'Select columns to hide

'Unhiding all colums
ws.Columns("A:GP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

'Hiding columns
ws.Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("F:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("Q:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("U:AC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("AE:AI").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("AK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("AR:AZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("BK:CL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("CQ:DX").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("DZ:EF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("EH:EM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("EO:EV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("EY:FB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("FD:FO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("FR:FW").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("FZ:GF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ws.Columns("GH:GP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

ws.Select
'Pasting values and formats

     ws.Activate

     ws.Cells.Select


    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Freezing cells
        
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
'Add Filter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
'Reduce zoom
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70

End Sub
```

There are times where I need to amend the columns hidden depending on the customer. Once a filter has been applied, the code runs ad returns the following error;

"There isn't enough memory to complete this action. Try using less data or closing other applications"

The spreadsheets aren't particularly large - up to 200 rows - and this message comes up regardless of anything else that is open. Any help is hugely appreciated, I'm not the best with VBA and this has completely stumped me!